# How do I set the default page orientation for LibreOffice Draw?

Tags: orientation, libreoffice-draw

Every time I start a new document in LibreOffice Draw, I have to change the orientation to landscape.

I can't find anything in the options about making this the default.

How do I change the default Page Setup values so that Orientation is Landscape for all new documents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directions for changing the default template for libreoffice are [here](http://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Changing_Default_Templates).

- Open draw, change the page format to landscape
- Save the blank file as a template,
  `File/Templates/Save`; give your template a name in the New Template
  box, and click OK
- Set the new template as the default template 
       `File/Templates/Organize`;Double-click on My Templates, click on your new template. Click on the down arrow in the Commands button, and pick Set as Default
  Template, then click OK.